# After properties set equivalent in Spring test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, initializing

I have a class like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MainConfig.class})
public class AbstractCSVFileProcessOpTest {

   @Autowired
   FileSource fileSource;

   @Autowired
   ReadFileOp readFileOp;
```

can I execute something after autowired fields initialized? Someting like `InitializingBean` in tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to execute a particular method immediately after the constructor has done its work.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MainConfig.class})
public class AbstractCSVFileProcessOpTest {

    @Autowired
    FileSource fileSource;

    @Autowired
    ReadFileOp readFileOp;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // do your task here
    }
}
```

*The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.*

Also, you can take advantage of [`@BeforeClass`](https://dzone.com/articles/enhancing-spring-test) from `junit` to execute a method before running your tests from that particular class.

Comment: I need to run code after `fileSource` and `readFileOp` is set. Not sure if `PostContruct` will do the job.

Comment: Yes, `@PostConstruct` is what you are looking for.