# Kotlin - How to manage @BeforeClass static method in springBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I want to have a @BeforeClass method in my springBootTest, which should be static and declared in "companion object".

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
open class MyTest {
companion object {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repo: MyRepository

    @BeforeClass
    @JvmStatic
    fun X() {
        user = User()
        repo.save(user)
    }

}
```

On the other hand I should use some Autowired components in this method, but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596751/can-i-write-a-kotlin-extension-function-that-uses-an-autowired-spring-bean/50090579) is not possible in static context and I got this error:

```
lateinit property repo has not been initialized
```

Any suggestion about how should I handle this situation?

Comment: Autowire cannot autowire static fields at all. 

Setup your repo before each test, not before the class is your only real option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch to Junit 5. It allows you to use `@BeforeAll` on regular non-static methods. Also, if you use Junit 5 Spring Extension, you’ll be able to inject dependencies into your `@BeforeAll`.

How you update the JUnit version will depend on which build tool you use (Maven or Gradle). Also you’ll need to replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)`.

You’ll also need to create the property file `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` with the content: `junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class`. With this, you will be able to use you to use `@BeforeAll` on non-static methods.

It might seem a lot, but JUnit 5 is a better fit if you're using Kotlin and Spring Boot.

Reference:  **Testing with JUnit 5** on [Building web applications with Spring Boot and Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/#_testing_with_junit_5)

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution. Autowired components don't get initialized when I replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)`. Any Idea?
Another problem is `@BeforeAll` method doesn't get invoked! I am using Maven.  I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441049/junit-5-does-not-execute-method-annotated-with-beforeeach) but still no luck.

Comment: Please post the new code, it will make it better to analyse the problem. You can see a working example of bean autowiring here: https://github.com/fabriciolemos/kotlin-spring-boot-lab/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/example/blog/ArticleResourceTest.kt

Comment: the problem was spring-boot-starter-test dependency in my pom.xml, which is using junit4 (unless you exclude it). I excluded junit from spring-boot-starter-test in pom and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to upgrade to JUnit5 you can use `@PostConstruct` it will have the same effect. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43961751)